# html,php,sql form with table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have html form with PHP & MYSQL queries which select data from a database and displays it in a table, now I am struggling to divide that table in pages if its too long, and to make first row of table to be clickable and sort data appending based on what header is pressed. I managed to do that but with a classic table, not one which is inside the form and submit button. Here is a part of my code.

```
 <form id="form6" name="form6" method="post" action="user.php">
      <p class='p1' id='pAll'>DISPLAYING ALL DATA
      </p>

      <div class='div1'>
         <input type="submit" name="display_all_data" id="display_all_data" value="DISPLAY ALL DATA" />
      </div>

      if (isset($_POST['display_all_data']))
      {
        echo "<script>window.location.href='#pAll';</script>";


        echo "<table align='center' class='table2'>
        <tr>
         <td width='5%'><a href ='?page=orderID'>ID</a></td> //something like this is what I need, but it works only with classic table which is load on page load, not after button is pressed

         <td width='25%'>NAME</td>

        </tr>";



SQL stuff.... and displaying rows
       {

         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td width='5%'>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td width='25%'>" . $row['NAME'] . "</td>";

         echo "</tr>";
       }

      echo "</table>";
      echo "</div>";
     }
    ?>
    </form>
```

So I need this table to have option to display more pages, and option to sort depending on selected column, for example ID

and when I press ID column to sort ID by ASC but I can't do that because I have table which is showing only if submit button is pressed not if td column is pressed.

I hope you understand my question, feel free to ask for more info if you can help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in simple terms what is the aim of your project???

Comment: for start, I would like to have option to sort table based on what header is pressed, ID, NAME, YEAR for example, if I press ID I want to be displayed by 1,2,3,4, if I press name I want to be displayed A,B,C etc, I can do this but with classic table, my table is displayed if submit is pressed only, not on page load.

Comment: yeah still dont know what u mean by the line `but with classic table, my table is displayed if submit is pressed only, not on page load` i mean what is ur definition of classic table

Comment: Classic table when pages load to display instant table, without form with submit button and php code with isset option, in my example

<div class='div1'>
     <input type="submit" name="display_all_data" id="display_all_data" value="DISPLAY ALL DATA" />
  </div>

 if (isset($_POST['display_all_data']))
  {

this will only show table

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little bit ambugues.

- If you need just table sorting support on the client side. You should use a library like http://tablesorter.com/docs/ or similar (pure jquery or own javascript implementation)
- If you want to add paginating in case of huge amount of date. You should implement it in your server side by selection portion of records check an example here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm

Comment: I am trying right now your second suggestion, but I am not sure if this will work inside of form, I tried something similar before and didn't worked. Thanks for your suggestions, I will post back with result

Comment: Ok here is problem, I am having already isset for one button input submit which will display table, when I press that button it loads my table even tho I have code from your suggestion inside my first isset, my isset is POST method and your is GET. I have few errors and NEXT 10 records link, which loads my page again, but with no table showed

Comment: There in no big difference in parsing GET or POST requests. And it works well inside a form but you need to change a logic. in case of  form you could use hidden field to keep current page/record count to pass to the script so you will have only next button... BTW: Perhaps it's better to make your solution more sophisticated with AJAX and other stuff...

Comment: so far I did not found solution, and I see this topic is not that much popular since I recieved -3 quickly, anyhow this is more php problem than any other, I had idea recently to find plugin that will refresh only table, not whole page, and parhaps press submit button with new table instant after refresh, for example when I press button Display all data, it will show table with 10 pages, after pressing page number 2 it will refresh table and load page 2 of table, and main page will stay unchanged

Comment: This question is not popular because it pretty broad. There are a lot of tutorials and materials which can describe how to solve your problem. Whether you use AJAX to prevent page reloading or standard mechanism, you need to update your whole approach. Check the following links: http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/ajax-pagination-with-jquery-php

Comment: I understand you guys, I know there is lots of examples, but no one figured or explained my problem in their example, I do not have table load on page load, my table is loaded after pressing submit button, and only then, so when I get pagination after button is pressed and first page of table is loaded, and I press page number 2 I just get my page without table loaded, and submit button to load table with page 1 again